# Assign array values to NaN Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to fill a dataframe which originally has NaN values with the same number of values taken from an array. All the values in the dictionary `leagueList` (NFL,NBA, etc.) are individual dataframes.
Sorry, I can't place them here as the post will become too long.

The idea behind the loop below is to get the series of paired t-tests (p_value) between all leagues in the dataframe and compare them based on columns called `'win_loss_ratio'`.
The resulting array with the same number of values as in the empty dataframe should be used to replace the NaN values in the dataframe but I am stuck on this part. How this could be accomplished?

```
leagueList={'NFL':NFL,'NBA':NBA,'NHL':NHL,'MLB':MLB}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = leagueList, index = leagueList)

print(df)
     NFL  NBA  NHL  MLB
NFL  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NBA  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NHL  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
MLB  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN


#Double loop for making all possible league combinations

for a in leagueList.values():
        for b in leagueList.values():

            df_comb=pd.merge(a,b,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='inner')
            
            teststat,p_value=stats.ttest_rel(df_comb[['win_loss_ratio_x']],df_comb[['win_loss_ratio_y']])

print(p_value)

[nan]
[0.94179205]
[0.03088317]
[0.80206949]
[0.94179205]
[nan]
[0.02229705]
[0.95053998]
[0.03088317]
[0.02229705]
[nan]
[0.00070784]
[0.80206949]
[0.95053998]
[0.00070784]
[nan]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the p-values into a list to either use `.fillna`, or just construct it straight a way:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

#some sample data
NFL = pd.DataFrame([.5,.6,.7], columns=['win_loss_ratio'])
NBA = pd.DataFrame([.7,.5,.3], columns=['win_loss_ratio'])
NHL = pd.DataFrame([.4,.3,.2], columns=['win_loss_ratio'])
MLB = pd.DataFrame([.9,.8,.9], columns=['win_loss_ratio'])

leagueList={'NFL':NFL,'NBA':NBA,'NHL':NHL,'MLB':MLB}


#Double loop for making all possible league combinations
rows = []
for a in leagueList.values():
        for b in leagueList.values():

            df_comb=pd.merge(a,b,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='inner')
            
            teststat,p_value=stats.ttest_rel(df_comb[['win_loss_ratio_x']],df_comb[['win_loss_ratio_y']])
            rows.append(p_value[0])

n=len(leagueList)
data = [rows[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(rows) + n - 1) // n )]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = leagueList, index = leagueList)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
          NFL       NBA      NHL       MLB
NFL       NaN  0.622036  0.12169  0.057191
NBA  0.622036       NaN  0.07418  0.092735
NHL  0.121690  0.074180      NaN  0.013560
MLB  0.057191  0.092735  0.01356       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea. Could you elaborate a bit on your list comprehension?

Comment: ya so what that's doing is just breaking up the 1 list of all the values, into a list of n items. Which in this case is list of 4, since there's 4 columns per row.  There's other ways you could do it though, just a matter of getting those values in a list of list. or dictionary